# how to create a RDS instance in VPC that is publicly accessible

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I want to create a RDS instance in VPC using boto.rds, which is publicly accessible. But can't able to do so. it is by default no public access.

I know using boto.rds2 a publicly accessible instance can be able to create. but i want to do it using boto.rds Does it possible?

or

After creation of instance, modify it as publicly accessible using boto.rds2 also works.

Comment: Does your Subnet have access to the Internet Gateway via the Routing Tables? Also, when you created the instance, did you specify you wanted to be able to access it from the outside?